# Relationship between Binomial and Poisson Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose I have an average of 10 cars passing through a street in an hour.

1 Hour = 3600 sec

Assuming 1 sec = single trial of a binomial distribution I have a binomial distribution with parameters n = 3600 and p = 10/3600. In this case Poisson distribution is a good approximation for the binomial distribution.

What happens when I have lesser values of n. Lets say n = 2? In that case the probability of numbers of cars passing in a single trial itself would be greater than 1.

Where I am going wrong or how to explain this?

Comment: What do you mean by Poisson distribution being a good approximation of a binomial one in the former case?